# React Hook : Correct way of using custom hook to handle onClick Event?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

As the title said, what is the correct way of using custom hook to handle onClick Event?

This [codesandbox application](https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-black-kze6g?file=/src/App.js) will display a new quote on the screen when user clicks the search button.

```
function App() {
  const [{ data, isLoading, isError }, doFetch] = useDataApi(
    "https://api.quotable.io/random"
  );

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <button disabled={isLoading} onClick={doFetch}>
        Search
      </button>
      {isError && <div>Something went wrong ...</div>}
      {isLoading ? <div>Loading ...</div> : <div>{data.content}</div>}
    </Fragment>
  );
}
```

I created a custom hook called `useDataApi()` which would fetch a new quote from an API. In order to update the quote when the user clicks the button, inside the `useDataApi()`, I created a `handleClick()` which will change the value of a click value to trigger re-render. And this `handleClick()` function will be return back to `App()`

```
const useDataApi = initialUrl => {
  const [data, setData] = useState("");
  const [click, setClick] = useState(true);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [isError, setIsError] = useState(false);

  const handleClick = () => {
    setClick(!click);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      setIsError(false);
      setIsLoading(true);
      try {
        const result = await axios(initialUrl);

        setData(result.data);
      } catch (error) {
        setIsError(true);
      }
      setIsLoading(false);
    };
    fetchData();
  }, [initialUrl, click]);

  return [{ data, isLoading, isError }, handleClick];
};
```

This is working, however, I don't feel this is the correct solution.

I also tried moving the `fetchData()` out of `useEffect` and return the `fetchData()`, and it works too. But according to the [React Doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-it-safe-to-omit-functions-from-the-list-of-dependencies), it says it is recommended to move functions inside the `useEffect`.

```
const useDataApi = initialUrl => {
  const [data, setData] = useState("");
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [isError, setIsError] = useState(false);

  const fetchData = async () => {
    setIsError(false);
    setIsLoading(true);
    try {
      const result = await axios(initialUrl);
      setData(result.data);
    } catch (error) {
      setIsError(true);
    }
    setIsLoading(false);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return [{ data, isLoading, isError }, fetchData];
};
```

In addition, for creating these kinds of application, is the way that I am using is fine or there is another correct solution such as not using any `useEffects` or not create any custom Hook? 
Thanks

Comment: Your question is a bit weird. It looks good to me. Why do you think it is wrong?

Comment: Because I have to create a handleClick() inside the custom Hook? I kinda feel weird of having that function to trigger re-rendering.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this is correct, but here is my solution.

```
const useDataApi = initialUrl => {
  const [data, setData] = useState("");
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [isError, setIsError] = useState(false);

  const doFetch = async () => {
    setIsError(false);
    setIsLoading(true);
    try {
      const result = await axios(initialUrl);

      setData(result.data);
    } catch (error) {
      setIsError(true);
    }
    setIsLoading(false);
  };

  return [{ data, isLoading, isError }, doFetch];
};
```

Btw, don't mutate state directly.

```
const handleClick = () => {
    setClick(!click);         // don't do this
    setClick(prev => !prev);    // use this
};
```

Comment: Thanks, there is no useEffects? I thought React says it is recommended to put any side effects such as fetch or time interval inside the useEffects?

Comment: Never mind, I think I got it. You code will not trigger the componentDidmount because it doesn't has the useEffects. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your implementation is fine. We are also using something similar. Hope you find it useful.

```js
function useApi(promiseFunction, deps, shouldRun=true){
  // promisFunction returns promise
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)
  const [data, setData] = useState(false)
  const [error, setError] = useState(false)
  
  const dependencies: any[] = useMemo(()=>{
    return [...dependencyArray, shouldRun]
  },[...dependencyArray, shouldRun])
  
  const reload = () => {
    async function call() {
      try {
        setError(null)
        setLoading(true)
        const res = await promiseFunction();
      }
      catch (error) {
        setError(error)
      }
      finally {
        setLoading(false)
      }
    }
    call();
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if(!shouldRun) return
    setResult(null) //no stale data
    reload()
  }, dependencies)
  
  return {loading, error, data, reload, setState: setData}
}
```

Below code will provide some idea about how to use it.

```js
function getUsersList(){
  return fetch('/users')
}

function getUserDetail(id){
  return fetch(`/user/${id}`)
}
const {loading, error, data }  = useApi(getUsersList, [], true)

const {loading: userLoading, error: userError, data: userData}
 = useApi(()=>getUserDetail(id), [id], true)
```

Comment: Thanks, Would you mind share the code of calling this useApi()? I am a little bit confuse on the " setState: setData"

Comment: I have updated the answer to accomodate usage of hook. Please let me know if something is still not explaining.I am just exposing setData function as setState so that calling components can see setState which is more obvious than setData.

Comment: Thank, appreciate it.